# menu > Project > Store is not enabled(windows xamarin crossplatform)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I created a Xamarin portable platforms app which contains four projects, Portable, Android, iOS and Windows Phone. When I make the Windows Phone project the start up project and then select menu > Project > Store, the store menu is disabled. St this point I am not able to reserve an app name or link my app to a registered app name. Menu item Associate app with the store is also disabled. Is there anyway of fixing this problem, I have no way of publishing my app.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to publish your app is through the dashboard. Go to http://dev.windows.com.

Sign in, reserve your app name and setup all the artwork etc for your app.

Then when you compile your Windows Phone or Store app, just get the generated file (.xap or .appx) and upload.

But to make sure the Store menu option is enabled also try these things.
1. Select the Windows Phone App in the solution explorer
2. Make sure you are in release mode
3. Make sure you have it compiling for ARM.

However I have never actually deployed from Visual Studio (something I should check in to). All I have in my menu is launching the Windows App Certification Kit.

Comment: i am developing xamarin cross-platform application, 
how to generated (.xap or .appx) file.

Comment: When you Build your project folder in the Bin > Release > ARM the file will be generated there.

Comment: I tried to install that file in  Bin > Release >,but it is not working

Comment: What actually happened. Is there an error message, is something not clickable?